# Hardware ID that maintains uniqueness when imaged

Tags: c#, security, wmi, licensing, hardware

I am currently trying to create a unique HWID for a C# application. My current implementation uses the CPU, BIOS, BaseBoard and Disk via WMI. However the issue I'm facing is when the system is imaged the HWID matches the original unit. Is there anything I can do?

The burden passed onto the user is not really a concern since if any of there hardware is swapped out (Including the hard drive) they are going to call us anyways.

Comment: Is using the NIC MAC address an option? Usually I avoid it if possible, but if you're going to be maintaining the machines, I guess you could manage the changes?

Comment: I thought about that but I was unsure if it would maintain uniqueness against imaging. Are you confident that is the case? I assumed since it's a breeze to change your MAC it would also likely change when imaged.